# mongodb- huge insert time on sharding

Tags: mongodb

I am having a problem with insertion time of 300,000,000 documents into collection. 
I was checking the performance of insertion time with a single node for the same count of documents. The time taken was approximately 23 minutes.

I create 2 shards - and trying to insert the same count of documents. The insert time is more than 25hours.

The two shards have a configuration of 8 GB RAM, 8 Cores machines.
The config and router are on the same machine which is of 4 GB RAM, 4 cores machine.

I am using C# driver - in my app- creating BSON documents for insertion.

The collection structure is:

```
Logs{
            "_id" 
            "LID"
            "Ver"
            "Y" 
            "M" 
            "D" 
            "H" 
            "Min" 
            "Sec" 
            "MSec" 
            "FID" 
    }
```

The shard key is _id field. The chunkSize of sharding is set to 1.

What are the things i should check on where the performance is creating a problem?
Can anyone suggest me a solution or the things i should look into to find the factors which are increasing the insertion time

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"30,00,00,000"?* You are using a strange number format. Either you misplaced the commas or you missed some zeros. Is this supposed to be 300 million or 30 billion?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is due to the [chunk migration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-migration/). Basically while you are inserting time the data is also moved from one shard to another. And then it might move back to the same shard. Also the thing can be that the indexes are eating some of your time (this is common thing that in databases creating index and then inserting data is slower then inserting data and creating index).

So if I were you, I would do the following:

- create 1 node mongo and insert all data into it. Without `db.coll.insert()` but by using [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/).
- then create indexes on whatever fields are needed.
- then shard your collection

Also you might try to [disable balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#sharding-balancing-disable-temporally) for the time of insertion.

Comment: I havent added any indexing as of now. The only index is on the field _id which is there by default.

Comment: So you shard based on **_id** index, which first of all is not a good idea, and also because of this you have a lot of chunk migrates. Anyway, have you tried my approach or do you have some problems with it?

Comment: how can i use mongodump for insert using a C# driver? I am new to mongodb.

Comment: Have your read mongodump documentation? It is written there how to use it. It is a standalone command and can be used without anything. If you are so new, most probably sharding is not the first concept you have to start with.

Comment: The question is how to insert without using db.coll.insert() ?

Comment: The answer- create 1 node mongo and insert all data into it. Without db.coll.insert() but by using mongodump and mongorestore- Can i know the other ways i can insert without db.coll.insert() command? Can you help me with the command or ways to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use it with db.coll.insert(). But most probably it will be slower. You can try googling how to use mongodump and mongorestore. There are a lot of answers here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, i got to know how to use mongodump and mongorestore. But how would it help improve the performance? Inserting into 1 node, dump data, later restoring the data and sharding- would help save some insert time? rather than directly inserting on sharded nodes?

Comment: Because mongorestore will restore documents much faster then if you will copy them one by one with insert. You do not need to insert document on 1 node. You told that you have already done this. So you need just to dump data and restore on one node. Then to shard the data.

Comment: Trying to create dump with the data which is already inserted. Using the command: **mongodump --db Parser --collection Logs** There are around 100,000,000 documents inserted. It is taking more than 12 hours for dumping. Is it the usual behavior? or is that i have appoarched it the wrong way.